# Angular Router - named router-outlets under children routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I try to use multiple router outlets in my Angular app. I experience problems whenever I try to use multiple router outlets inside my shell container.

The intended behaviour is to have both the main component and the details component to be rendered when I visit their paths:

[image: detailsshownbutflatroutes]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9omb3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

However, in this example, the app-routing.module uses a flat route structure without any children routes.

```
// app-routing.module.ts in flat solution
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: EmptyShellComponent },
  {
    path: 'feature1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./feature-one/feature-one.module').then(
        (m) => m.FeatureOneModule
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'feature2',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./feature-two/feature-two.module').then(
        (m) => m.FeatureTwoModule
      ),
  },
];
```

How I want my routes in the app.routing-module to look like:

```
//app-routing.module.ts in solution with children routes
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: EmptyShellComponent },
      {
        path: 'feature1',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./feature-one/feature-one.module').then(
            (m) => m.FeatureOneModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'feature2',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./feature-two/feature-two.module').then(
            (m) => m.FeatureTwoModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

However, when I use this structure I don't manage to get the router-outlet for the details to render anything: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yasztr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

[image: nodetailsshown]

What approach should I take to tackle this problem to allow multiple router outlets in the children modules of the shell?

### EDIT

A requirement is that I would like to have a designated space for the details view at the shell-level, where one can load different detail components from different modules. Is this possible somehow? I want to be able to view feature1's main component at the same time as I am viewing feature2's details and I want both modules to be lazy loaded.

### EDIT 2

By adding an the named router-outlet in the app.component.html I get the following state:

[image: detailsoutsideofshell]

The details from the different module is rendered, but outside of the shell.

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahptuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Don't nest route outlets yourself. Your right about defining `children: []` to define child routes. Instead of forcing router within a router `<router-outlet><router-outlet></router-outlet></router-outlet>` nest children one more level deep.  https://blog.devgenius.io/the-art-of-nested-router-outlets-in-angular-dafb38245a30

Comment: Hi @Joosep.P ! Thanks for your reply. Please see my comment to Akash Garg's answer.

Comment: @maac Hi, do you found a solution to this use case, cause I have the same "problem" right now ...

Answer (score 2):

Angular routing can have up to one ***primary*** router outlet, and zero or more ***auxiliary*** router outlets. To create an auxiliary outlet, just give it a unique name.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
```

The primary outlet is optional, you can name them all if you want. From my testing, it looks like Angular will only render one outlet for each unique name.

To assign a path to the `aux` outlet, just add the `outlet` property to a `Route`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'features',
    component: FeatureOneComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'features',
    component: FeatureTwoComponent,
    outlet: 'aux',
  },
];
```

Now both components appear at the `features` path.

Another solution would be to just put both components in an enclosing component, and use a single router-outlet to navigate to it.

More info on navigating auxiliary paths here: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/#Create_Named_Router_Outlet

If you want to put a router outlet *inside* of another routed component, you can use the `children` array: https://blog.devgenius.io/the-art-of-nested-router-outlets-in-angular-dafb38245a30. You don't need to give nested router-outlets unique names.

Comment: Thank you Chris! The app component currently uses a primary router-outlet, and the shell uses a primary router-outlet and one named router-outlet, but this should be alright since the router-outlet of the app component is used to router to the shell component? Therefore we maintain the requirement to only have one primary router-outlet?  I want to use two router outlets as I want to be able to route the detail view regardless of my primary router-outlet.

Comment: Angular will only render the first level of router-outlets it finds (the highest in the component tree) if you have more router-outlets inside of the rendered component, you need to put paths for those inside the `children` array of the parent path. Yes you can have another primary router-outlet at each level.

For example if I have router outlet in app.component.html, and two more in `SomeComponent`. I can render `SomeComponent` using the path `somePath`, then I can add the two paths for the `SomeComponent` outlets in the `children` array of the `somePath` object. Make sense?

Comment: I believe so. The issue is that I would be able to have one designated space for the details view at the shell-level, where different detail components from different modules can be loaded. Is this possible somehow? I want to be able to view feature1's main component at the same time as I am viewing feature2's details and I want both modules to be lazy loaded.

Comment: You legend, this is documented so poorly, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case of children routes, what you are talking about is nested router outlet where the multiple router-outlet directive is not part of one component html. In that case naming of outlet is not required. You can read more at :-

https://blog.devgenius.io/the-art-of-nested-router-outlets-in-angular-dafb38245a30

Comment: Hi Aakash. Thanks for your reply. Not sure if I understand what you mean. I want to be able to render two independant views under the shell component. In your provided example we rather seem to be interested in rendering one of many children routes inside some feature container. I may have misunderstood the article?